# setListAdapter only showing 1 result from query

Tags: android, database, listview

So I finally got my listview to display result(s) from my db query, but for some reason its only showing 1, the last.

```
public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);



    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String[] listData = new String [] {"Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Strokes: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Holes: " + c.getString(3)};
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.pastgames, listData));
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();


}
}
```

dbadapter

```
//***RETRIEVES ALL THE FINALSCORES***//
public Cursor getAllFinalscores()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE,
            KEY_FINALSCORE,
            KEY_HOLESPLAYED},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?  Why is it not displaying each row in the db?

EDIT:  Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

NEW (Correct way):

```
public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);


    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
    String[] listData = new String[c.getCount()];
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
    do {

        listData[c.getPosition()] = "Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "Strokes: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Holes: " + c.getString(3);
    }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.pastgames, listData));
    }
    db.close()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the Do While loop. You are currently recreating the array and filling it with one element each time. So the final one is the only one that is displayed (the rest were overwritten). You should instantiate the array out of the do while loop, then fill it within the loop, and finally attach it to the list view.

On a side note, I generally use ArrayLists to create my content because that way I do not need to determine how large it will be when instantiating the array. Arraylist has a method .toArray. that will turn it into an array for you.

Comment: Thank you Pyrodante for the suggest I understand now my problem but how can I instantiate the array out of the do while loop ?

Comment: I did this but I get some logCat error now 
if (c.moveToFirst())
     { 
      String []listData=new String[70];
         do {
              int i=0;
              listData[i]=c.getString(0);
             i++;
         }
         while (c.moveToNext());
         this.setListAdapter...
     }

Comment: If you choose to simply use an array you could define it 
String[] listData = new String[c.getCount];
That should make the array the size that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are *replacing* your list adapter each time through the loop. in fact, you don't need to loop through the results yourself at all; use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) instead. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html) and [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) for sample code on how to use one.

Comment: thank you Ted, in this line how can I get the URI of my own data base? ( I replace People.Content_URI by what?
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {People._ID, People.NAME, People.NUMBER}, null, null, null);